# I need the equivalent of .load() to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm developing a script but I mustn't use jQuery library so I need the equivalent of .load() in JS.

I need to do this without jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#a').click(function(){
   $('body').append('<div id="b"></div>')
   $('#b').load('x.html')
});

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe use `<iframes/>`?

Comment: Check body's onload event

Comment: "I need to do this without JS"  I assume you mean without jQuery?

Comment: Open up jQuery's file and read its method

Comment: "I need to do this without JS" I assume you mean without jQuery? – ben336 1 min ago"  Yes sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is you're doing things that are fairly complicated to get done correctly without a library like jQuery. Here's something that "works", but with no error checking or cross-browser perfection. You really probably don't want this... but here it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.id = 'b';
                document.body.appendChild(div);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.onload = function () {
                    div.innerHTML = this.response;
                };

                xhr.open('GET', 'x.html', true);
                xhr.send();
            }, false);
        }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="a" href="#">load</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16):

### UPDATE:

#### Using Fetch API with .then()

```js
function load(url, element)
{
    fetch(url).then(res => {
        element.innerHTML = res; 
    });
}
```

---

#### Old XMLHttpRequest

```js
function load(url, element)
{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, false);
    req.send(null);
    
    element.innerHTML = req.responseText; 
}
```

---

### Usage

```js
load("x.html", document.getElementById("b"));
```

Comment: what if I want the async version of this function?

Comment: @eeadev, It's async by default, so you can simply remove the `false` from `req.open()` or change it to `true`. See [XMLHttp​Request​.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open)

Comment: note that jquery load will execute js on the loaded page (just like you loaded a page into a frame), whereas just setting the html will not

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it without JS, I think this will help you, add this inside `#b`

```
<iframe src="x.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

## UPDATE:

### Using Fetch API with .then()

```js
function load(url, element)
{
    fetch(url).then(res => {
        element.innerHTML = res; 
    });
}
```

---

### Old XMLHttpRequest

```js
function load(url, element)
{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, false);
    req.send(null);
    
    element.innerHTML = req.responseText; 
}
```

---

### Usage

```js
load("x.html", document.getElementById("b"));
```

> This will load "x.html" and put it inside the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<object type="text/html" data="my.html">
```

Comment: the object tag of html, the one which is used to add plugins, [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

/* If you wanted post too */    
// xmlhttp.open("POST", "/posturl", true);
// xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// xmlhttp.send("email=" + "value" + "&message=" + "value" + "&name=" + name"value");

xmlhttp.open("GET", "file_to_get.xml", true/* async, setting to false will block other scripts */);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        window.alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that jquery load run scripts from loaded file, which setting innerHTML to something doesn't do the trick... don't test if you can call an init() function afterwards...

Comment: Could you maybe expand on your answer? Or maybe write a short snippet that shows what you are trying to say here?