# how to load div in one file from another (inside iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to load data from the appropriate file into `div` sections when I select any option.
I need to load `<div>` in one file from another (inside iframe). I'm stuck on how to get value and store it in variable. Everything works fine if I assign to variables (`template_1`, `template_2`, `template_3`) any static data but I want to load it from another files (`template_one.html`, `template_2.html` and so on).

`template_1` has `load()` method but I know that this is wrong. Instead I want a path to appropriate file div. Same with other variables

I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901116/i-need-the-equivalent-of-load-to-js) with `function load` but I'm not sure if this will work and how add this to my function.

Array objects are random so please don't worry about it

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var template_1 = $('#section_one').load('template_one.html', '.section_one')
  var template_2 = "<div><h1>template2</h1></div>"
  var template_3 = "<div><h1>template3</h1></div>"
  var templates_array = [
    [template_1, template_1, template_1, template_1, template_1],
    [template_2, template_2, template_2, template_2, template_2],
    [template_3, template_3, template_3, template_3, template_3],
  ]

  function load(url, element) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, false);
    req.send(null);
    element.innerHTML = req.responseText;
  }

  document.getElementById('id_template').onchange = function(event) {
    let get_val = event.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("value");
    if (get_val) {
      for (let i = 0; i < templates_array.length; i++) {
        var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i].contentWindow.document;
        var iframe_content = iframe.querySelector('body');
        iframe_content.innerHTML = templates_array[get_val - 1][i];
      };
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < templates_array.length; i++) {
        var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i].contentWindow.document;
        var iframe_content = iframe.querySelector('body');
        iframe_content.innerHTML = '';
      };
    };
  };
});
```

[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p930d.png)

Comment: I solved a similar problem once by having javascript in the iframe document which calls a function of the parent.

Comment: Thanks for answer but without any sample code I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

### Jquery Code

```
         $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('click', '#button_1', function() {
            $('#div_1').load('one.html')
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#button_2', function() {
            $('#div_2').load('two.html')
        })

    });
```

### HTML Code

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="button_1">Button_1</a>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="button_2">Button_2</a>
    <BR>
    <BR>
    <div id="div_1"></div>
    <div id="div_2"></div>
```

I hope this one help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the iframe:

```
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '#ta', function() {
        parent.textAreaChanged(this.value);
    });

});
</script>
```

In the parent:

```
<div id="display"></div>

<script>
function textAreaChanged(value){
    $('#display').text(value);
}
</script>
```