# how to get header tag without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted this code to work without needing to use jquery to get the header tag:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
   <script> 
     $(function(){ $("head").load("header.html") });
   </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Don't confuse the header tag (`<header>`) with the head tag (`<head>)` they are quite different.

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 1.x is beyond end of life and has known security issues. Use a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: I dont know why you should do that but...

fetch("urlToGetData").then((data)=>{return data.text}).then(function(textBodyResponse) {
    document.querySelector('#div').innerHTML = textBodyResponse;
  });

asume head is not header or something like that 

Regards

Comment: For getting the head use document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

Comment: For equivalent to .load(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901116/i-need-the-equivalent-of-load-to-js

Answer (score 3):

How's this?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML
```

Or if you are in fact looking for header tags:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].innerHTML
```